# User control in a page with a page level grid

Tags: user-controls, grid

I have an aspx page with a Telerik RadGrid right on the page.  Then there is a user control embedded in the page with a seperate TeleRik Grid.  When a row is dragged from the page level grid to the user control grid I am having trouble finding the UserControl.Grid  When using intellisense, the UserControl.Grid does not show up.  I need to be able to grab the UserControl.Grid and do some work on it durnig the Row Drop event.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The grid inside the user control should be accessible on the client my its ClientID despite it resides inside a user control (since the user control does not rendering additional html element). On the server you can reference the user control grid by invoking the FindControl(gridId) method for the user control instance.